# Debug two instances of the same project in VS with different database configurations

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I want to debug one of the solutions while being able to write code in the other one and debug this one.

Basically, I want to make sure that I'm working on different DB (that's why I use different configs) and that the data doesn't mix inappropiately.

Right now, I have opened one of them in debug mode, and the other one in release mode.

Is this scenario correct? It is very important that one of them doesn't cause any problems so I'm unsure about launching them just like this. Some reassurement would be great.

Comment: How does your code get the database configuration?

Comment: Through the config file, in connectionstringssettings